# Calling two entities in return Ok()

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have got the result of two entities which contains the list. Is there a way to pass them with status 200?

I can pass one entity as `return ok(entity1);`

Comment: Create a new class with two properties, one for each entity model and return that.

Comment: Just return a different object or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that by:

```
return Ok(new {
 firstEntity = entity1, 
 secondEntity = entity2 

});
```

Comment: May be accidentally. :) It worked. Thanks.Looks like someone has downvoted my question...